# What is free will?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, free-will

I'm sorry if I'm wasting anyone's time with a dumb question but I'll try to explain the way I see things.

So, if God created a world where you can't levitate, see through walls etc, and I want to do those things, do I still have free will?

What about sin, hurting other etc? Why did God created a world where I can hurt other peoples, where we can kill each other, etc? If we can't do these things and this results in losing our free will, the fact that we can't levitate results in losing free will too, right?

And I'm not talking about physical laws or biological properties that does not allow us to levitate, because if we say that, there could also be physical laws and biological properties that makes us unable to hurt others.

Comment: Since the question assumes a "God" and refers to the argument that humans need the ability to hurt others to retain free will, likely this is the wrong forum to ask this question. A better place might be https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/22784/why-doesnt-god-stop-suffering, but even then, the question should likely be improved, such as adding reference to the original argument and explaining which of the many, many possible gods and scriptures are relevant to the question.

Comment: You might be unable to levitate, but you are free to WANT to do so. So your free will is not constrained in this regard. In the same way, I can be unlawfully put in prison by a corrupt judge, and wand to hurt him, but being unable because I am behind bars and he is miles away in the courtroom. My inability to do it has no bearing on my desire to do it, which is unrestrained in this regard. Those are two different problems.

Comment: Whether you have free will in the various scenarios you asked depends on what you mean by “free will”. This term can have several different meanings. Please check out these references to see what meanings it can have: [Plato Standford](https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2016/entries/freewill), [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://www.iep.utm.edu/freewill/), [Free Will and Determinism](https://mindtheory.net/chapter-12/).